# Copy a File to current login in users desktop Mac

Tags: shell, applescript, file-copying, fileshare

I need a command or something that will allow me to send a file to the current logged in Mac user without manually setting this file location up. Can this be done?
Example I have a file called test.app I want to copy this to the users desktop. I don't know what the current users name is and I want it to be pickup automatically and then copy the file down to the user.

Comment: Is there any way to copy the file with that automatically. I want to copy a plist file down and it will be all done automatically. I can't sit there and do a ls command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use ~/Desktop/test.app as the file location. It will put it on the desktop of the current user.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

To find out the all the users, use:

```
do shell script "cd /Users; ls"
return result
```

This should return the users in the "Result" tab in the Event Log at the bottom of the AppleScript Editor.

Then to copy test.app, use this:

```
do shell script "cp -R /path/to/test.app /Users/whateveruser/Desktop/test.app"
```

And that should copy the file to whatever users desktop you want.

Hope this helps!